# cancelling tbb Parallel_reduce causes Memory Leak

Tags: tbb

In a program I am working on we are using tbb::Parallel_reduce and a user has the ability to cancel the program midway, we are doing this by throwing a custom exception.  When the exception is thrown the destructor of a single thread is being called while the rest are just left, and since each thread is making a copy of some of the data (needed for processing) there can be extremely large memory leaks.  Normally this wouldn't be a problem however this code is being run inside of another program so the operating system will not be able to free the memory.

The main question I have for this is does anyone know a way to force the destructor of each thread to be called when an exception is thrown or another way of being able to clean up the data.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was fixed in TBB 4.2, here is an excerpt from the CHANGES file:

> Bugs fixed:
>
> - Fixed a leak of parallel_reduce body objects when execution is
>        cancelled or an exception is thrown, as suggested by Darcy Harrison.